# Pandas DF will in for Missing Months

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe of values that are mostly (but not always) quarterly values.

I need to fill in for any missing months so it is complete.

Here i need to put it into a complete df from 2015-12 to  2021-03.

Thank you.

```
    id      date        amt     rate
0   15856   2015-12-31  85.09   0.0175
1   15857   2016-03-31  135.60  0.0175
2   15858   2016-06-30  135.91  0.0175
3   15859   2016-09-30  167.27  0.0175
4   15860   2016-12-31  173.32  0.0175
....
19  15875   2020-09-30  305.03  0.0175
20  15876   2020-12-31  354.09  0.0175
21  15877   2021-03-31  391.19  0.0175
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A solution I can think of is to generate all the quarterly dates, create a dataframe and join with your dataframe. If you do a left join on generate and actual, the dates that are missing in your data will have the `id` column as null (since it did not find a match)

Comment: just some crazy loop...not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.date_range()` to generate a list of months end with `freq='M'` then reindex datetime index.

```py
df_ = df.set_index('date').reindex(pd.date_range('2015-12', '2021-03', freq='M')).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'date'})
```

```
print(df_)

         date       id     amt    rate
0  2015-12-31  15856.0   85.09  0.0175
1  2016-01-31      NaN     NaN     NaN
2  2016-02-29      NaN     NaN     NaN
3  2016-03-31  15857.0  135.60  0.0175
4  2016-04-30      NaN     NaN     NaN
..        ...      ...     ...     ...
58 2020-10-31      NaN     NaN     NaN
59 2020-11-30      NaN     NaN     NaN
60 2020-12-31  15876.0  354.09  0.0175
61 2021-01-31      NaN     NaN     NaN
62 2021-02-28      NaN     NaN     NaN
```

To fill the NaN value, you can use `df_.fillna(0)`.